# Drawing in OpenGl Andengine Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, bezier

I am using AndEngine.
Now the problem is that I want to draw bezier curves on the scene. I know there is not built in functionality to do this.
So I computed the points etc in a custom fashion. Now I am stack that how can I draw the lines on the scene.

I overridded the method

```
    myScene = new Scene()
    {
         @Override
        protected void onManagedDraw(GL10 pGL, Camera pCamera) {

             log("Draw","in Draw");

            super.onManagedDraw(pGL, pCamera);
        }
    };
```

The log is working fine. The code I used for line drawing.

```
 public static void DrawQuadBezier(GL10 gl, CGPoint origin, CGPoint control,
        CGPoint destination, int segments) {

    FastFloatBuffer vertices = getVertices(2 * (segments + 1));

    float t = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        float x = (float)Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * origin.x + 2.0f * (1 - t) * t * control.x + t * t * destination.x;
        float y = (float)Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * origin.y + 2.0f * (1 - t) * t * control.y + t * t * destination.y;
        vertices.put(x);
        vertices.put(y);
        t += 1.0f / segments;
    }
    vertices.put(destination.x);
    vertices.put(destination.y);

    vertices.position(0);

    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.bytes);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, segments + 1);

    // restore default state
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
}
```

Now when I call this method giving it the required parameters nothing is drawn on the screeen. Can any one help me with it. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are drawing in the visible area?

I'd ensure that by trying to draw a single line that I'm sure of that it is visible.

Comment: Are you calling super.onMangedDraw() before or after calling DrawQuadBezier()? Try calling DrawQuadBezier() after super.onManagedDraw(). I'll try it out and post my results.

Comment: yeh I have tried both ways before and after called super.... but no result. I think Nicolas is right.
@NicolasGramlich I think I dont know and dont know a way to know if I am drawing on visable area. Can you help ?

Comment: Set the camera to show the area from 0,0 to 100,100. Draw something between 0,0 and 100,100. Done.

Comment: no result:(. WHat to do now?. Actually I want to draw bezier line directly on GL. How can i do this?